# stage to fact continuous

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, data-warehouse

How do I make a continuous record if the fact end date is the same as the state end date, but I want to preserve the fact start date and just update the enddate of the fact to the stage enddate contain multiple records that show the accurate start and end date of each continuous commitment. An example of this is patid 1001 and when there is a continuation of the same status without a gap, it should be a single record.

```
-----key index CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [fact_fact_patient_lega_idx_A] ON [fact].[fact_patient_legal_status]
--(
--  [patid] ASC,
--  [dim_start_date_key] ASC,
--  [dim_legal_status_key] ASC
--)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
--GO

--Synchronize the target table with refreshed data from stage table

MERGE into [fact_patient_ls] AS TARGET
USING CTE_legal_status AS SOURCE ON (TARGET.ClaimID = SOURCE.ClaimID  
                                     AND TARGET.dim_legalstat_key = SOURCE.dim_legalstat_key 
                                     AND TARGET.order_start_date = SOURCE.order_start_date) 

--When records are matched, update the records if there is any change
WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.order_end_date <> SOURCE.order_end_date OR TARGET.days_committed <> SOURCE.days_committed
    THEN 
        UPDATE 
        SET TARGET.order_end_date = SOURCE.order_end_date, 
            TARGET.days_committed = SOURCE.days_committed,
            dss_update_time = GETDATE()

--When no records are matched, insert the incoming records from source table to target table
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN 
        INSERT (ClaimID, dim_legalstat_key, order_start_date, order_end_date, days_committed, dss_create_time, dss_update_time)
        VALUES (SOURCE.ClaimID, SOURCE.dim_legalstat_key, 
                SOURCE.order_start_date, SOURCE.order_end_date,
                SOURCE.days_committed, GETDATE(), GETDATE()
               );

----data loaded in Fact 
INSERT INTO [fact_patient_ls] (ClaimID, dim_legalstat_key, order_start_date, order_end_date, days_committed, dss_create_time, dss_update_time)
VALUES (80953, 18, 2016-09-28, 2021-11-15, 1874, '2023-08-18 09:42:55.360', '2023-08-18 09:42:55.360')

----Incoming data from stage
INSERT INTO [STG_fact_patient_ls] (ClaimID, dim_legalstat_key, order_start_date, order_end_date, days_committed, dss_create_time, dss_update_time)
VALUES  (80953, 18, 2021-11-15, 2023-08-28  ,651, '2023-08-18 09:42:55.360','2023-08-28 00:05:21.200')

            ----Current Output in Fact Table(unwanted)
            (80953, 18, 2016-09-28, 2021-11-15, 1874,   '2023-08-18 09:42:55.360',  '2023-08-18 09:42:55.360')
            (80953, 18, 2021-11-15, 2023-08-28, 651,    '2023-08-19 00:05:04.620',  '2023-08-28 00:05:21.200')


            ---desired output in fact for a single row when startdate=prev_endate 
            (80953, 18, 2016-09-28, 2023-08-28  ,2525, '2023-08-18 09:42:55.360','2023-08-28 00:05:21.200')
```

Comment: In your example, the order_start_date of the fact table (2016-09-28) is different to that in staging (2021-11-15), but the MERGE uses that as part of the join key. if you want to match purely on claimid & legal_stat_key, then change the ON condition there.